# Understanding Proposition 1.1 Chapter XII in Lang Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> $\textbf{Proposition 1.1}$. Let $|\ |_1$ and $|\ |_2$ be non-trivial absolute values on a field $K$. They are dependent if and only if the relation $|x|_1<1$ implies $|x|_2<1$. If they are dependent, then there exists a number $\lambda>0$ such that $|x|_1 = |x|_2^\lambda$ for all $x\in K$.

The proof shows $\Leftarrow$ direction by actually showing existence of such $\lambda$. Once such existence of $\lambda$ is proved, then can we say two absolute values are dependent i.e. they induces the same topology on $K$ by rather easy argument. Is this what the proof is saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two absolute values are called *equivalent* if $|x|_1=|x|_2^t$ for some $t>0$ and all $x\in K$. Then the following lemma, which shows what you ask, is easy to prove.

*Lemma:* Let $|\;|_1$ and $|\;|_2$ be two absolute values on $K$, and $|\;|_1$ be nontrivial. Then the following
statements are equivalent.

(a) $|\;|_1$ and $|\;|_2$ define the same topology on $K$.

(b) $|x|_1<1 \Rightarrow |x|_2<1$.

(c) $|\;|_1$ and $|\;|_2$ are equivalent.

Comment: Yes. What I'm asking is $(c)\Rightarrow (a)$ which is almost straightforward right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. By $(c)$ an $\epsilon$-neighborhood with respect to $|\;|_2$ is an $\epsilon^t$-neighborhood with respect to $|\;|_1$. Hence the two topologies coincide.